# repeated values with group_concat and joins

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a little problem with the following Query. It returns multiple values.

Here is the result I'm receiving:

```
+----+--------------+--------+--------+---------------------+----------+------------------+
| id | company      | county | vm     | os                  | products | sn               |
+----+--------------+--------+--------+---------------------+----------+------------------+
| 1  | ABC Corp     | USA    | VMW    | Linux, Linux, Linux | 3        | A123, B234, A343 |
| 2  | DEF Corp     | USA    | CIT    | Windows             | 1        | I223             |
+----+--------------+--------+--------+---------------------+----------+------------------+
```

As you can see, the first line shows 3 times Linux, but this should be only listed once. I've seen that this problem only occurs if the customer has more than 1 product. I think i have to Group my Query or something like this, but i don't know how.

Here is my Query:

```
SELECT
    customer.id,
    customer.company,
    countries.en AS country,
    vmenv.name AS vm,
    GROUP_CONCAT(operatingsystems.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS os,
    COUNT(device2customer.sn) AS products,
    GROUP_CONCAT(device2customer.sn SEPARATOR ', ') AS sn
FROM
    customer

LEFT JOIN
    countries
ON
    customer.country = countries.id

LEFT JOIN
    vmenv2kunden
ON
    vmenv2kunden.customerid = customer.id

LEFT JOIN
    vmenv
ON
    vmenv2kunden.vmenvnr = vmenv.id

LEFT JOIN
    operatingsystems2customer
ON
    operatingsystems2customer.customerid = customer.id

LEFT JOIN
    operatingsystems
ON
    operatingsystems2customer.osnr = operatingsystems.id

LEFT JOIN
    device2customer
ON
    device2customer.kundenid = customer.id

GROUP BY
    customer.id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query change the group_concat statement to

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT operatingsystems.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS os,
COUNT(DISTINCT device2customer.sn) AS products,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT device2customer.sn SEPARATOR ', ') AS sn
```

By adding the DISTINCT key word it should work for you

Comment: Okay, in this case I have to use DISTINCT also for COUNT device2customer and GROUP_CONCAT device2customer. Is it the right way to use it several times, or can I do all this in another, better way?

Comment: Yes, you have to write `DISTINCT` in every `GROUP_CONCAT` and `COUNT` because you're just formatting the output and don't want to change the rest of the result. If you write `DISTINCT` after the `SELECT` keyword then you'll just get unique lines and that's not good enough here since it'll look at the whole line and not look for duplicates within the `os` field.

Answer (score 1):

you just need yo use `distinct` in `Group_concat`.

Please try the below updated Query.

```
SELECT
    customer.id,
    customer.company,
    countries.en AS country,
    vmenv.name AS vm,
    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct operatingsystems.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS os,
    COUNT(device2customer.sn) AS products,
    GROUP_CONCAT(device2customer.sn SEPARATOR ', ') AS sn
FROM
    customer

LEFT JOIN
    countries
ON
    customer.country = countries.id

LEFT JOIN
    vmenv2kunden
ON
    vmenv2kunden.customerid = customer.id

LEFT JOIN
    vmenv
ON
    vmenv2kunden.vmenvnr = vmenv.id

LEFT JOIN
    operatingsystems2customer
ON
    operatingsystems2customer.customerid = customer.id

LEFT JOIN
    operatingsystems
ON
    operatingsystems2customer.osnr = operatingsystems.id

LEFT JOIN
    device2customer
ON
    device2customer.kundenid = customer.id

GROUP BY
    customer.id
```

Comment: Okay, in this case I have to use DISTINCT also for COUNT device2customer and GROUP_CONCAT device2customer. Is it the right way to use it several times, or can I do all this in another, better way?